# Odd C# path issue

Tags: c#, c, string, path, slash

My C# application writes its full path surrounded by double quotes to a file, with:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine("\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
```

Normally it works, the written file contains

```
"D:\Dev\Projects\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe"
```

But, if the executable path of my application contains a #, something weird happens. The output becomes:

```
"D:\Dev\Projects#/MyApp/bin/Debug/MyApp.exe"
```

The slashes after the # become forward slashes. This causes issues with the system I am developing.

Why is this happening, and is there a way to prevent it that is more elegant than string.replacing the path before writing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I have my app running from C:\my#\project\foo.exe and it writes out the Application.ExecutablePath correctly as you have written above.  When you debug does Application.ExecutablePath inspect correctly?  Are you doing any post-processing on the text you write out that isn't shown here?

Comment: I re-tested it in a new project, with just the code to write the file. It still reproduces. The framework it's using is 4.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Interesting, especially in light of Elian's post below.  Wonder what I did differently (though I used the 4.0 framework...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just looked into the source code of `Application.ExecutablePath`, and the implementation is essentially this*:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string cb = asm.CodeBase;
var codeBase = new Uri(cb); 

if (codeBase.IsFile) 
    return codeBase.LocalPath + Uri.UnescapeDataString(codeBase.Fragment);
else
    return codeBase.ToString();
```

The property `Assembly.CodeBase` will return the location as an URI. Something like:

> `file:///C:/myfolder/myfile.exe`

The `#` is the fragment marker in a URI; it marks the beginning of the fragment. Apparently, the `Uri` class alters the given uri when it's parsed and converted back to a string again.

Since `Assembly.Location` contains a 'normal' file path, I guess your best alternative is:

```
string executablePath = Assembly().GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

**) The implementation is more complex than this, because it also deals with situations where there are multiple appdomains and other special situations. I simplified the code for the most common situation.*

Comment: Interesting issue.. anyway, I converted to Assembly.Location and it's resolved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Odd error/bug.  Other than using a replace function or extension method to always return the correct format you could try using

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

instead of ExecutablePath.